# Что такое член класса?

Tags: c#

Можете подробно объяснить член класса в C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это любая сущность, которая [может быть объявлена](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx) в классе:

- константа
- поле
- свойство
- метод
- событие
- индексатор
- оператор
- конструктор
- деструктор
- статический конструктор
- вложенный тип